# Cannot update git module within docker container

Tags: git, docker, git-submodules

I have got a project that has some dependencies. They are defined in `.gitmodules`. I want to make sure the modules are up to date.
So, here's what I do in the `Dockerfile`.

```
RUN git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And it gives me the error: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

The directory is fine. I checked `ls -a` right before this line and the folder is correct.
The git is also up to date (`2.11`).

It just doesn't see `.gitmodules` no matter what I do.

Do you guys have any thoughts about what might cause this?

**EDIT:** Here are the relevant parts of the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/docker_container
ADD ./ /home/docker_container/
WORKDIR /home/docker_container/my-project

RUN git submodule update --init --recursive && \
mkdir build && cd build && \
cmake .. && cmake --build . && cd ..
```

The the folder structure is like this:

| my_project:

|--- module1

|--- module2

|--- some source code and `.gitmodules` file

Comment: Have you set `WORKDIR` respectively at dockerfile? You should verify that `git submodule ..` is executed at the correct directory.

Comment: @leopal yeah, right at the beginning

Comment: Anyway, I think you should update your post to include your Dockerfile.

Comment: where is you `.git` folder in your structure?

Answer (score 0):

can you modify your command like this:

```
RUN pwd && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then check the output.

For me the error means you are not in the correct folder.

To check that it is not a submodules problem you  can try to run "git fetch" instead and I guess you would get the same error.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: `RUN pwd` prints the right path, that's not the issue.

Comment: If the path is right, then maybe the .git is missing. You can test the same with "ls -la" instead pf "pwd". Also if you have a .dockerignore in your folder you should check that as well to see what is not copied by ADD inside the container.